# Why does my state still holds deleted value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I have created a simple React ToDo App

```
const [list, setList] = React.useState(['Call Sina', 'Do Laundry'])
  const [task, setTask] = React.useState('')

  const addTask = (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault()
    setList((prev)=> {
      setTask('')
      console.log(task)
      return [...prev, task]
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>CodeSandbox Todo</h1>
      
      <form onSubmit={addTask}>
        <input 
        type="text" 
        value={task}
        onChange= {(event)=>{
          setTask(event.target.value)
        }}
        />

        <input 
        type="submit" 
        value="Add task!"
        />
      </form>

      <ul> 
      {list.map(str => <li>{str}</li>)}
      </ul>

    </div>
  );
```

in the function addTask,

```
  function addTask(event)
{
    event.preventDefault()

    setList( prev => {
      setTask('')
      console.log(task)
      return [...prev, task]
    }
)
```

why does the console.log(task) not show an empty string when I've already set it to empty the line before? what kind of asynchronous voodoo magic is this?

Answer (score 1):

The `setState` is an `async` operation, in fact, it should update fine, but after the `console` log the old value.

**Just for `text` purpose**, you can use `setState` callback to log the latest value.

```
function addTask(event) {

    event.preventDefault()

    setList( prev => {
      setTask('')
      setTask(prev => {
        console.log(prev) // should log the new value (empty string).
        return prev;
      })
      console.log(task)  // should log the old value.
      return [...prev, task]
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically the `setState` is an `asynchronous` operation, aka the line below it can or in this can will get executed before this, but the value of prev will not be get affected beacause it has already been called, at some point of time there will exist 2 value of task

1. inside the `setTask` function: task == `previous value`
2. inside the `setList` function: task == ""